# Google search console issue "redirected"

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I have a website made with **`wordpress`** that I approved that to `google search console` with `www` version and without **www** version and `without www is my preferred version.`

My website language is `Persian`.

When I submit a URL like this:

`http://example.com/اجاره-آپارتمان-مبله-در-اصفهان`

google say that this URL is redirected to a URL just like the first one:

[image: first step issue]

Click on the URL in the list will show up:

[image: second step]

This is what google shows me when I click on the `redirected` word to see what is happening, and **if I click on the *follow* button, google will fill ASCII code of my URL words instead of original words. It seems this page is redirected to itself!**

[image]

This is my `httpd.conf` lines to handle my website:

[image: server configuration]

And finally my page does not apear to google after two months!

Do you know what's the problem here and How Can I fix the problem?

***Thanks in Advance***

Comment: I checked your URL [here](http://apartemanesfahan.ir/اجاره-آپارتمان-مبله-در-اصفهان) in an HTTP viewer and it seems to return a `200` (without a redirect). There are some reported issues with Fetch as Google not handling Persian URLs properly. Try encoding your URL using an online site like [this](http://www.url-encode-decode.com/) one, make sue the encoded URL is reachable in a browser, and then try submitting that instead. If your URL contains special characters, you may need to research how to encode those specifically if online services are not able to.

Comment: @dan thanks for your comment. I figured it that the problem exists even if I use english characters, for example I did change my URL to `mysote.ir/moble` but again search console return `redirected`! What do you think about this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my eyesight is good, the destination url ends in a slash (/) while the original one does not.